# Ethernet Overloading Problem During Launch Robot

Tags: ros2, turtlebot4, create3

I'm currently facing an issue in my turtlebot4 project where I observe a significant spike in internet usage when launching ROS 2 processes. After a while, the usage returns to normal. I suspect this issue might be related to the connection with the discovery server.

The primary packages I'm using are ros2_control and nav2, but it's challenging to confirm if the problem is specific to these packages.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem, especially concerning excessive internet usage during the connection to the discovery server? If so, could you share your insights into solving this issue? Additionally, are there any specific configurations or settings related to ros2_control and nav2 that might affect the interaction with the discovery server?

I appreciate any help or advice on detecting and resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Is your Create3 showing 100% CPU utilization in your situation?  
See https://github.com/iRobotEducation/create3_docs/issues/381